# Storing realcolor images in an array for MATLAB

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, animation, image-processing

I am working on an m file that would take out single frames from a bigger image and play them as an animation. So far I managed to create the algorithm to locate and crop individual frames.

I can also store them in cell arrays. Almost everything is already done really.
My problem is that I can't get them to animate. I used the animation functions but they do not work. The reason being is that they are in cell arrays instead of just 4D arrays.

I want to store each frame in a nXmX3X(frame_number) array. How can I do that? How can I replace only the nXm part of an array?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a cell array `cFrames` with `n` cells each storing the `k`-th frame of size `m`-by-`n`-by-3, you can use `cat` to create the desired 4D array

```
>> frames4d = cat(4, cFrames{:} );
```

Note: **all** frames in `cFrames` must have the same size for this to work.

Comment: Yes it has worked thanks to you I have my own animation program now =) Just a question: I can't quiet understand what ':' does when addressed. Could you tell me please?

Comment: @Ocul the `{:}` means that it takes all the cells in `cFrames`. For further reading see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/10/all-about-the-colon-operator/).